# R data.table rolling join etc to add dynamics to previous period

Tags: r, data.table, self-join

There is a data.table, which has some data for different id's on yearly basis:

```
example_data <- data.table(
  id = c('id1', 'id1', 'id1', 'id2', 'id2', 'id2', 'id2', 'id2'),
  year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2014, 2015),
  param1 = c(10, 10, 20, 10, 5, 7, 15, 15),
  param2 = c(100, 150, 200, 50, 50, 75, 15, 10),
  param3 = c(100, 100, 0, 500, 0, 400, 500, 1000)
)
> example_data
    id year param1 param2 param3
1: id1 2010     10    100    100
2: id1 2011     10    150    100
3: id1 2012     20    200      0
4: id2 2010     10     50    500
5: id2 2011      5     50      0
6: id2 2012      7     75    400
7: id2 2014     15     15    500
8: id2 2015     15     10   1000
>
```

I need to add three columns, so that for each id I get a ratio of each param for previous year.
I managed at least to make three new columns with just the values of params for previous year:

```
try01 <- example_data[example_data, on = .(id, year < year), mult="last"]

> try01
    id year param1 param2 param3 i.param1 i.param2 i.param3
1: id1 2010     NA     NA     NA       10      100      100
2: id1 2011     10    100    100       10      150      100
3: id1 2012     10    150    100       20      200        0
4: id2 2010     NA     NA     NA       10       50      500
5: id2 2011     10     50    500        5       50        0
6: id2 2012      5     50      0        7       75      400
7: id2 2014      7     75    400       15       15      500
8: id2 2015     15     15    500       15       10     1000
```

This is ok, but here the original data is on the right side of the table, and previous values are on the left - it would be better to add new columns to the right instead.

And the original question is - how can I directly add not values from previous years, but the ratio " param current year / param previous year"?
May be I could use shift or similar command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with the suggestion of using [`shift()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/shift.html). That will be a lot quicker than doing a (cartesian) non-equi join and then subsetting the last value.

```r
param_cols <- grep("^param", names(example_data), value = TRUE)
new_cols <- paste0(param_cols, "_ratio")
example_data[, (new_cols) := lapply(
    .SD,
    \(x) x / shift(x)
),
by = id,
.SDcols = param_cols
]

#        id  year param1 param2 param3 param1_ratio param2_ratio param3_ratio
#    <char> <num>  <num>  <num>  <num>        <num>        <num>        <num>
# 1:    id1  2010     10    100    100           NA           NA           NA
# 2:    id1  2011     10    150    100     1.000000    1.5000000         1.00
# 3:    id1  2012     20    200      0     2.000000    1.3333333         0.00
# 4:    id2  2010     10     50    500           NA           NA           NA
# 5:    id2  2011      5     50      0     0.500000    1.0000000         0.00
# 6:    id2  2012      7     75    400     1.400000    1.5000000          Inf
# 7:    id2  2014     15     15    500     2.142857    0.2000000         1.25
# 8:    id2  2015     15     10   1000     1.000000    0.6666667         2.00
```

I've assumed you want the first value to be `NA` as there is no previous value. However, if not, you can change the `fill` parameter in your `shift()` call. For example, if you want it to always be 1, just divide by the first value by group, `shift(x, fill = x[1])`.

Similarly, you will get `Inf` rather than `NA` if the previous value is `0`. If you don't want this you replace all the infinite values with `NA`, e.g. after the previous stage:

```r
example_data[,
    (new_cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(is.infinite(x), NA, x)),
    .SDcols = new_cols
]
```

Comment: For brevity (only), I often put the `c(paste0(..))` on the LHS of the `:=` assignment within data.table's `[`. (It changes nothing but reduces the need for `new_cols` ... I have found inadvertent updating of one of `param_cols`/`new_cols` but not the other leads to confusion/errors, so I tend to avoid that when able. Someday we'll be able to do something like `names(.SD) := lapply(.SD, ...)`